# Line of Sight blockage using bitmaps

Tags: rasterizing

I'm building a simulation model for a vehicle.  I must determine if the vehicle's line of sight is being blocked by other vehicles in the sim.

(There is no visual display for our sim, it's purely for calculations.)

One idea is to generate a view with the camera at the line of sight's origin and orientation.  Then I rasterize the scene into a black and white bitmap, with black meaning blocked, and white meaning clear.

Does this seem feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this in 2d or 3d? Also, have you considered using an existing simulation frame such as [Gazebo](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/gazebo.html) or [Microsoft Robotics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/default)?